# Create date with 15th of month from Month name in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the month names in the A - column, like "January" in cell A1.
Furthermore I have the year in the B - column like "2019” in cell B1. 
How can I now create a formula to get a result of 15/1/2019 for each row in the C - column?
Thank you in advance

A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DATEVALUE() and CONCATENATE the date:

```
=DATEVALUE("15"&A1&B1)
```

Then format as desired:

[image]

---

We can leave off the `""` and use `--` instead of DATEVALUE: `=--(15&A1&B1)`

Comment: Thank you @scott, that was quick. But I’m getting a #value error ...

Comment: Are your months spelled correctly for your local settings?

Comment: Sorry, I had it formatted as date, not as Text, now it’s working. Thanks 